# Resize a DOM node hierarchy?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a fairly complex HTML DOM node tree that I want to copy and display elsewhere on the page, but with a different size. I.e. I want to scale it proportionally.

I can clone it with

```
copy = elem.cloneNode(true);
```

and it works fine when appended elsewhere. However it's the same size. Most of the elements have absolute sizing, and it's not practical to re-generate the content some of which comes from library functions.

Is it possible to scale the whole node hierarchy so it looks the same, just smaller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use CSS on the parent, e.g. `transform: scale(0.5)`

Stack snippet

```css
.original {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.scaled {
  transform: scale(0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="original"></div>

<div class="scaled">

  <div class="original"></div>

</div>
```

Details:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function#Browser_compatibility